# Fullpage rebuild is not triggered

Tags: fullpage.js, rebuild

I have a slide with dropdown-menus (drawers). The drawers are all collapsed in the beginning, and once opened, there's not enough room left in the slide. I tried to rebuild manually after opening the drawer, but it doesn't work.

```
var myFullpage;
    myFullpage = new fullpage('#fullpage', {
    licenseKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    verticalCentered: false,
    loopHorizontal: false,
    scrollOverflow: true
    });

    $(".drawer-header").click(function(){
         $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("active");
         $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");

         myFullpage.rebuild();    
    })
```

I'm using jQuery, I got a license for fullpage.js and I'm using the scrollOverflow-Addon.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```js
fullpage_api.reBuild();
```

Comment: I get a "Uncaught TypeError: myFullpage.rebuild is not a function"

Comment: Exactly... that's why if you read my answer again you'll see I told you to replace `myFullpage` for `fullpage_api` :)